# How do I best handle a simple column replacement in a database using a java program?

Tags: java, database, file, architecture

I have a table A [id,name] and it has about say, 10 million records. I need to replace all names with 10 million unique names. So, for this I have a text file that acts as a lookup file and it has 10 million names in it separated by new line. So, bunch of questions:

- How do I go about randomly replacing these 10 million names in the
  database with 10 million names in a text file? - I can think of a few approaches, caching the entire file, and creating a map of what is being replaced, so that I never reuse entries from lookup file.OR use a database table, load look up file into it and make use of this table.
- In general, what would be a good number for # of writes/ # of reads that would make it a case for using database against using a file? Say, if your program is reading a file million times and writing to another file million times, would you switch to using database? What's the upperlimit really (if there is any)?

Comment: Is there a mapping from the existing names to the new names? How do you choose the new name for an existing name?  Your question is rather unclear.

Comment: Yes, say, its 1, John; 2, Paul; 3, Harry; and I have Jacob, Smith, Rick in my look up file. The mapping would be, John-Jacob. Now when I go about replacing Paul, I cannot use Jacob, just have to use one of Smith or Rick.

Comment: That's not a mapping; that's a random selection without reuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well lets think, you have THAT many names, that it cant be all loaded into the memory, so we are going to find the solution as usable as possible.

For random approach you can create temp column in database, create the Unique key over it and always use this :

```
1)take a name on line "x" (by random or whatever you want) 
2)random record "y" in database which was not replaced yet (it can be tracked with just one boolean) 
3)try to add the name on line x to the record y AND to the same record add x to the temp column. 
4)if Unique errorcomes, it means the name was already given to someone, repeat once more with another x.
```

If we can track "x" and we are sure, we are not using alredy given names, we dont need the Unique modifier.

Comment: the only problem with this approach is that the number of unique key exceptions will be less in the beginning but as you get to the end the you will end up reading randomly a lot of times just to replace one record.

Comment: well if you dont choose names on line x randomly, the database query allows you to choose random record from itself ONLY from the non-used records. Something like "SELECT Random() FROM People where is_used = true"

Answer (score 1):

1. Instead of replacing the names randomly if i would have been in your place I would have opted for a batch based approached where I would have processed the data in chunks. Have a reader to read the chunk, a processor to update new values from the file and a writer to write back the updated values to a database.
2. Your second question is a bit unclear. The decision to go with files is purely based on the requirement. If you are getting the data in flat files you will have to read from that. Even if there are billions of rows moving all the data from a flat file to database table and then again using it to update another table is an overkill. You are unnecessarily persisting data which you are not going to use later on once the intended table column is updated.